# How to define a subroutine/macro in sperate .asm file?

Tags: c, assembly, avr, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm programming in AVR for Atmega32 using AtmelStudio. I was wondering how you can write a subroutine or function in a separate file and then call it within `main.asm`?

current issue is I have a subroutine `genArrays` inside of `genArray.asm` .
Using `.include "genArray.asm"` at the start of `main.asm` causes the program to run `genArray` immediately at the start of `main.asm` when i don’t want it to be called until i actually call it using the call instruction (example below)

---

main.asm:

```
.include "genArray.asm"
.org 0x0000
start:
...
... ---- ; do some stuff
...
...
call genArrays ---- ; call to genArrays subroutine that is defined in genArray.asm (separate file)
... ---- ; return here and continue with program
... ---- ; do some more stuff
```

---

genArray.asm:

```
genArrays: ---- ; start of subroutine
...
...
...
... -----; do some stuff
...
ret
```

Comment: Declare the symbol globally. Then you have to call the function in another file using the correct setup/tear down instructions. Link them together so the symbols are resolved on the final binary.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu assembler/binutils.  I am very rusty on my avr, but...

so.s

```
    .globl _start
    _start:
    nop
    nop
    rcall fun
    nop
    nop
    here:
    rjmp here
```

fun.s

```
    .globl fun
    fun:
    nop
    nop
    ret
```

build

```
avr-as so.s -o so.o
avr-as fun.s -o fun.o
avr-ld -Ttext=0 so.o fun.o -o so.elf
avr-objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-avr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__ctors_end>:
   0:   00 00           nop
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   03 d0           rcall   .+6         ; 0xc <fun>
   6:   00 00           nop
    ...

0000000a <here>:
   a:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xa <here>

0000000c <fun>:
   c:   00 00           nop
   e:   00 00           nop
  10:   08 95           ret
```

assembly language is specific to the assembler, not the target, so you need to use the language for the assembler you are using, the above is gnu assembler for avr.  Likewise how you link them is very much tool specific. gnu ld has a myriad of features, AVR is a PITA to build for (from scratch) so you may want to use an already built toolchain and linker script.  (on linux I simply apt-got a toolchain).

As utterly horrible as this is:

```
avr-gcc -nostdlib  so.s fun.s -o so.elf
avr-objdump -d so.elf
    
so.elf:     file format elf32-avr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__ctors_end>:
   0:   00 00           nop
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   03 d0           rcall   .+6         ; 0xc <fun>
   6:   00 00           nop
    ...

0000000a <here>:
   a:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xa <here>

0000000c <fun>:
   c:   00 00           nop
   e:   00 00           nop
  10:   08 95           ret
```

works (thus far).

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple thing: put `.include "genArray.asm"` at the end of `main.asm` so its code will come after `main` in program memory.

That should be good enough for now.  You could also take a look at the assembly generated by `avr-gcc` and see how it defines its functions.

Comment: That's necessary for a *macro*, but a subroutine can be assembled into to a separate object file and then linked.  That avoids any mistakes with file-scoped label names or directives.